# Could not connect, retrying (3/3) - Server got hacked?

Tags: mysql, server, google-compute-engine, gcloud

My instance have been working fine for 1 month, but today, my client told me its not working,

When I go to compute engine page to SSH connect, it fail.

Its says, "Connecting... Could not connect, retrying (3/3)."

When I reboot the instance, my php page shown "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'", Its an LEMP server.

now, I can't access with ssh or sftp, whats should I do now? anyone know what happened?

---

Its LEMP. with mysql-client, mysql-client5.5, nginx server running websocket.

the instance is at : us-central1-f

Update:
now, the site are not even up.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on ServerFault?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. Now I resolved it. Let me explain this issue.

I discovered that the boot disk of instant is full. So you can not ssh to your instant.
After rebooted instant, mysql has been stopped. However you still can not access server via ssh to start mysql (service mysql start). Therefore your php page shown "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'".

Bellow are steps to solve this issue:

1. You create a new snapshot from boot disk of your instant (https://console.developers.google.com/project/), menu Compute Engine -> Snapshots
2. Create new disk from the new snapshot. The new disk should be larger than boot disk of your instant, such as 50Gb or 100Gb
3. Create new instant
4. Attach the new disk to your new instant
5. SSH to the new instant (you can use ssh browser of Google)
6. Check your disks: fdisk -l

You will see the new disk is /dev/sdb

7. Repartition the new disk by following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd
   Or try steps:

sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

- Delete old partition:

Command (m for help): d

- Create new partition:

Command (m for help): n

Partition type:

p primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)

e extended

Select (default p): p

Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1

First cylinder (2048-104857599, default 2048): 2048

Last cylinder, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-104857599, default 104857599):

Using default value 104857599

- Save new partition:

Command (m for help): w

- Then resize disk to physical size:

sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb1

8. Create new instant, set boot disk as the new disk which you've repartition
9. Now you have new instant with same data, same configuration as your old instant.
10. Delete your old instant. You don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your serial console output in the Cloud Console Instance Detail screen; it often has information about why core services haven't started. Then you should probably boot another instance with your disk as a secondary disk to check logs and see what went wrong. Both procedures are explained in detail here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot